# How can I download Redis package for php 8?

Tags: php, redis, php-8

I want use Redis cache on my Laravel website with php 8, PHP 8 does not provide Redis Package by default.How can I download Redis package for php 8?

I have try to download from website https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.1.1/windows

but only available for php 7 , not for php 8

Comment: 5.1.1 is from 2019. PHP8 was released in 2020. Use a more recent version; PECL Redis 5.3.7 is the latest, and works fine with PHP8. https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/5.3.7/windows

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/INSTALL.md

PHPRedis is compatible with PHP 8.x versions.

Comment: Yep; OP's just using an old version from 2019, before PHP8 existed. They just need to use a more recent version of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Select the most recent version of the **Redis** package from the following URL

- https://pecl.php.net/package/redis

For example, you can select the release [6.0.2](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/6.0.2) and you will be able to see the compatible PHP version for this particular package at the bottom of the page.

[image: dependency for the redis release]

Answer (score 1):

I have build a DLL for PHP 8.3 Windows x64

https://shuchkin.ru/2024/02/phpredis-for-windows-php-8-3-php_redis-dll/